# Getting Error on Php Internal Server Error

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am getting Error i tried to find but did not get why getting Error.While its working fine on my localhost but not working on live server.

http://wellnessvisit.com/vascular-new/assets/global/plugins/jquery-file-upload/server/php/

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@wellnessvisit.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Comment: Join the error logs and we might be able to help you.

Comment: How is everything configured? We can't do anything at all with this!!!

Answer (score 1):

Normally production servers are configured to hide all error information.

You can add these two lines in your main php file to see if there's a way to get the error information (temporarily, be sure to delete them after you're done debugging):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

You can also check if there's an error_log file in the same folder as your PHP script, many servers log the errors to a file.

If no luck, with the previous lines, it might be a syntax error so the parsing is not completed.